Queueing theory - connected queues stability condition

hey everyone, given a system with poissonian process split with probabilities p and q to queues with exponential serving times, notice you can move from being assigned to queue 1 to instead being assigned to the intermediate queue and then to the second queue.
why when looking at the second queue the stability condition: $$\mu_2 > (1-p)\lambda + \lambda p (1-q)$$ doesn’t it feature $\mu_T$ in the second term?
(these seem to be M/M/1 queues that are involved with each other).

no, due to conservation of customers

The rate coming out of the intermediate queue is going to be the lower of $\lambda p(1-q)$ and $\mu_T$, and $(1-p)\lambda + \lambda p (1-q) \ge (1-p)\lambda + \min\big( \lambda p (1-q), \mu_T\big)$ so it is a sufficient condition though in some cases not necessary.

can you please expand on conservation of customers?

what goes in must go out. therfore, if the queue releases them in a Poisson manner, the rate must still be the input rate. Unless, as Henry mentioned, the input rate is more that the output rate

So since we're looking for stability conditions and have demanded therefore $\mu_T > \lambda p (1-q)$, we know the output rate will be the $\lambda p (1-q)$  Thank you!!
